# Laravel BotMan: $botman->hears does not seem to be hearing anything

Tags: php, laravel, chatbot, laravel-10, botman

I'm working with [BotMan](https://botman.io/2.0/installation) in Laravel and I tried this steps for using this chatbot:

```
composer require botman/botman
```

Added this to `config/app.php`:

```
'providers' => [
    // ...
    BotMan\BotMan\BotManServiceProvider::class,
],
```

Then ran this command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="BotMan\BotMan\BotManServiceProvider"
```

Made a new Controller:

```
php artisan make:controller BotController

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use BotMan\BotMan\BotMan;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BotController extends Controller
{
    public function handle(Request $request)
    {
        $botman = app('botman');

        $message = $request->query('message');

        // dd('Before hears callback'); RETURNS SUCCESSFULLY

        $botman->hears('hello', function (BotMan $bot) use ($message) {
            dd('Inside hears callback'); // DOES NOT RETURN !!!
            $bot->reply("Received message: $message");
        });

        $botman->listen();
    }
}
```

Here is `web.php`:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\BotController;
use BotMan\BotMan\BotMan;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/botman', [BotController::class, 'handle']);
```

Then serve the project and visit this url for testing:

```
http://localhost:8000/botman?message=hello
```

But it does not return anything at all! Meaning that the **callback function being registered using the hears method in BotMan** DOES NOT seem to be working:

```
$botman->hears('hello', function (BotMan $bot) use ($message) {
    $bot->reply("Received message: $message");
});
```

So I would really appreciate if you could help me with this...

Comment: Maybe the message isn't being passed as a query parameter in the request, which could be why the hears method isn't triggering the callback.